# Swift: Access ARsession parameters through a UIbuttion click

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, projection-matrix, arcamera

I am trying to print the ARsession's parameters like the following. It works when I do it within a session.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
          guard let arCamera = session.currentFrame?.camera else { return }
          print("ARCamera ProjectionMatrix = \(arCamera.projectionMatrix)")
    }
```

---

Result:

```
ARCamera ProjectionMatrix = simd_float4x4([[1.774035, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 2.36538, 0.0, 0.0], [-0.0011034012, 0.00073593855, -0.99999976, -1.0], [0.0, 0.0, -0.0009999998, 0.0]])
```

---

However, I would like to access/print the parameters when a button is clicked. I tried the following:

```
@IBAction private func startPressed() {
    print(ARSession.init().currentFrame?.camera.projectionMatrix)
}
```

---

But the result above returns `nil`. Am I missing some obvious and can someone help me on how to correct this so I can properly access the camera parameters when the button is clicked?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing a new session by calling `ARSession.init()`, so there is no wonder it returns `nil`. You should use an instance of currently running `ARSession` instead. Assuming you are using `ARSCNView` to render the AR experience, correct code would look like this:

```
@IBAction private func startPressed() {
    if let matrix = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.projectionMatrix {
       print(matrix)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a follow up here, its possible to just print the matrix number? I am printing the type and optional as well.  `Optional(simd_float4x4([[1.774035, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 2.36538, 0.0, 0.0], [-0.0011034012, 0.00073593855, -0.99999976, -1.0], [0.0, 0.0, -0.0009999998, 0.0]])) `

Comment: You can unwrap `matrix` property to get rid of "Optional" in the print result. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks! I force-unwarpped it with ! and its gone! And also with the simd_float4x4 matrix type. Is there a way to not show it?

Comment: No way to do it as far as I know:)